# Is this natural deduction proof of $\exists x \neg Px \vdash \neg \forall x Px$ correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, computer-science, predicate-logic

When it comes to proofs there is no way to tell whether I have done correct or not. In the solution they did in another way which makes me wonder if this correct? For future question, how can I verify whether it is correct or not? I have heard of websites that can check but can't find any that works.
[image]

Comment: Why Line 5? What does it mean the $\exists$ as ref to the rule to be used?

Comment: Your proof appears to be correct, but it's not clear (to me) what rule you're citing on line $5$ when you annotate with "$\exists$." I'm guessing it's some sort of reiteration rule so that $\neg Pa$ appears in the same subproof as $Pa$, but I'm not sure why the existential quantifier would be used to annotate a reiteration rule. As for websites that construct logic proofs, a simple google search of "logic proof checker" will return a number of resources you can use.

Comment: After looking back at my proof, line 5 is a stupid error that should not be there. But aside from line 5 it is correct tho.

Comment: Yes, aside from line $5$ your proof is correct!